# Issue for the "change" event of "select" in ToolTipDialog execution times

Tags: events, select, dojo

Why  Select  **change** event execution times will increase with the number of button's click.

**HTML :**

```
<button id="btn">click me</button>
```

**JS**

```
require(["dojo/_base/declare", "dojo/dom", "dojo/on", "dojo/_base/lang", "dijit/registry", "dijit/TooltipDialog", "dijit/popup","dijit/form/Select", "dojo/_base/array", "dojo/domReady!"],
  function(declare, dom, on, lang, registry, TooltipDialog, popup,Select, Array) {
  var InfoWindow= declare( // 类名省略
    TooltipDialog,
    {
      constructor: function (parameters) {
        console.log("hello");

      },

      test:function(){
        var tNode=dom.byId("btn");
        var myTooltipDialog = new TooltipDialog({
          id: 'myTooltipDialog',
          style: "width: 300px;",
          content: '<div id="tpDialog006" class="pDlg"></div><div id="selectMenu" class="right"><select name="select1" id="sel006"  data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Select"> <option  value="037" selected="selected">1</option><option class="left" value="005" >2</option><option class="left" value="007" >3</option><option   value="006">4</option></select></div>',
          onMouseLeave: function(e){
            if(registry.getEnclosingWidget(e.target).name=="select1")
              return;
            popup.close(myTooltipDialog);
          },
          onOpen:lang.hitch(this, function(e) {

          })
        });

        var sHu = registry.byId("sel006" );
        sHu.on("change", function (e) {
          alert( "value is" +sHu.value);
        });

        on(tNode,"click",function(){
          popup.open({
            popup: myTooltipDialog,
            around: dom.byId('btn')
          });
        })
        this.m1="t1";

      }

    }
  );

  var infoWindow = new InfoWindow({
  });
  infoWindow.test(); 


});
```

The code is at the link:[code link](https://fiddle.jshell.net/etxx1o0s/9/)

there may be some problem for the tooltipdialog shows but it will not affect the issue to be reproduced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal that the click is reproduced because :

in the button click (above) :

```
on(tNode,"click",function(){
   popup.open({
      popup: myTooltipDialog,
      around: dom.byId('btn')
   });
})
```

In every button click you are opening the `Popup` so, the tooltip's `open` function is being executed ( `onOpen` event fired ) which means that the change event is attached again to your `sel006` `select` input .

What I propose to you is not to assign the select change event inside the tooltips `onOpen` event and just declare it after the toolTip initialization

So the code became :

```
var myTooltipDialog = new TooltipDialog({
                    id: 'myTooltipDialog',
                    style: "width: 300px;",
                    content: '<div id="tpDialog006" class="pDlg"></div><div id="selectMenu" class="right"><select name="select1" id="sel006"  data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Select"> <option  value="037" selected="selected">1</option><option class="left" value="005" >2</option><option class="left" value="007" >3</option><option   value="006">4</option></select></div>',
    onMouseLeave: function(e){
        if(registry.getEnclosingWidget(e.target).name=="select1")
        return;
        popup.close(myTooltipDialog);
    },
    onOpen:lang.hitch(this, function(e) {
        // remove event from here                 
    })
});

var sHu = registry.byId("sel006" );

sHu.on("change", function (e) {
    alert( "value is" +sHu.value);
});
```

Bellow a fiddle example : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xdDEm/117/)